# How do I get a div Box to fade in and out of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am currently working on a page here that uses checkboxes to display images and remove images. I have the add image and remove image part working. I just can't get the image to fade in and out of a div. Can anyone help?

```
<html><head>
    <style>
        .overlay {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;

        }
        .right {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    width: 300px;
    border:3px solid #8AC007;
    padding: 10px;
}
        #map {
            position: relative;
            right: -780px;
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            display: none;
            background: url(tn_bandannatop.png) 0 0;
        }
        #station_A { top: 5px; left: 85px }
        #station_B { top: 150px; left: 180px }
        .hover { color: green }
    </style>
<div id="map" >
        <span id="station_A" class="overlay"><img src="/tn_WhiskersPrinceworkup.png"></span>
        <span id="station_B" class="overlay">Highlight image here.</span>

    </div>

    <p>
        <h2>Choose a Shirt</h2>
        <form>
            <input type="checkbox" name="image" value="station_A">Station Alfa<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="image" value="station_B">Station Beta
            <input type="checkbox" name="image" value="bandanna" id="checkbox1">Bandanna
        </form>
    </p>

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {
    var state = $(this).val();
    //
    $("#"+state).toggleClass("overlay");
}); 
     $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#checkbox1').change(function(){
        if(this.checked)
            $('#map').fadeIn('slow');
        else
            $('#map').fadeOut('slow');

    });
});
  </script>
</body></html>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g3w33z09/)  is here

UPDATE:updated  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g3w33z09/3/)  is here added image urls.  Also the div map is supposed to fade in and out it is not working in the fiddle for some reason. Worked fine on my devbox.

Comment: Its working fine. http://jsfiddle.net/Rino_Raj/g3w33z09/4/

Comment: When I check the box "Bandanna", it fades in. I removed the width and the positioning and I can see the images fade in/out. You have them set to background. Can you describe exactly what you expect to happen? The Fiddle you will not see the images unless you scroll right after checking the box with your existing code. ** See Rino's fiddle, those are close to the results I come up with also after making a couple adjustments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Please try this.**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function () {
        var state = $(this).val();
        $("#" + state).toggleClass("overlay");
    });
    $('#checkbox1').change(function () {
        if (this.checked) $('#map').fadeIn('slow');
        else $('#map').fadeOut('slow');

    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Rino_Raj/g3w33z09/4/)